# rails: rake populating data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lot of users who has tags, and a lot of posts which has tags.

I want to autopopulate my database when I run rake db:populate. This is my code under lib/tasks:

```
def make_tags
   User.all.each do |user|
      5.times do |n|
        name = Faker::Company.bs
        user.tags.create!(:name => name)
      end

    end  
   Micropost.all.each do |micropost|
      3.times do |n|
        name = Faker::Company.bs
        micropost.tags.create!(:name => name)
      end
   end
```

However the problem is that usesrs and posts do not share the same tags, because a new tag is created each time. Is there a way to reference to previously created tags by their ids and so that I do not create new tags everytime?

Comment: did you try find_or_create instead of create in the second loop?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the structure of your app. A user creates a tag for a micropost? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'd use something along the lines of this:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  5.times do |n|
    name = Faker::Company.bs
    micropost = Micropost.find(:first, :offset => rand(Micropost.count))
    user.tags.create!(:name => name, :micropost => micropost)
  end
end
```

Does that doe what you need? It's demo/test data, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is your micropost associated to a user? If so use that association to set tags for both.

If not, regroup your code, generate a tag, then associate the same tag to a user and to a micropost.
Or first tag your users, then iterate through users and put user's tags to microposts.

Comment: the tags associated with the user is different from those associated with the post.

Comment: Tags for the user is like "skills" while tags are just tags for posts